# Удаление адаптации с сайта

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли удалить адаптацию на сайте, собранном в WordPress на Elementor? Понимаю, что бред, но клиенту очень хочется.

Comment: Какая ещё адаптация? Адаптивность к разным размерам экрана?

Comment: Да, именно адаптивность к разным размерам. Ее нужно убрать.

Comment: https://www.wpzoom.com/docs/remove-responsive/

Comment: Ну а вообще клиенту надо объяснить, что он хочет глупость. Он сайт самому себе будет показывать? До 90% трафика идёт с мобилок, и люди будут просто уходить, увидев эти мелкие тексты и картинки. Поисковики тоже сильно понижают ранг не адаптивного сайта в выдаче.

Comment: Я все это делал, но сайт не реагирует. Возможно, потому что собран в Elementor?